# How do I spin down an HDD with the command line?

Tags: hard-drive, batch-file, cmd.exe

I have an SSD and an HDD on my laptop, and want a command to safely spin the second one down. I have played around with the mountvol commands, however even after I had disabled all the partitions in the drive, it kept making the spinning sound. I especially need a cmd command and NOT other fixes (e.g. device manager etc.), so I can turn my drive on and off any time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SATA/eSATA drives you could use
[HotSwap!](http://mt-naka.com/hotswap/index_enu.htm),
described as:

> It does the same thing as you can remove device from Device Manager but it provides much friendly user interface as you remove the removable device from the "Safely Remove Hardware" icon in the notification area. It also ensures that all data are written and flushed to the disk before the device to be hot-swapped, so you can use SATA/eSATA drive as a removable device much alike USB/IEEE1394 drive.

This does not prevent Windows from waking up the disk with some request.
You should ensure that the disk is not indexed by Windows or any installed utility,
or accessed for any reason.

Comment: Sounds nice, just got a question: if i have disabled my disk in the current boot session, will it allow me to turn it back up (with "scan for hardware changes" probably?)

Comment: Any reference to the disk will wake it up. It is quite possible that the disk will restart periodically, when some Windows service interrogates its status. That's why all such references should be disabled for the disk. I don't have a list for them. Trying and seeing if it works for your disk controller and for how long will give you a better idea.

Answer (score 3):

On any kind of Linux, you could probably achieve this with

```
sudo hdparm -Y /dev/sdX
```

because the options of `hdparm` are

```
-y   Put drive in standby mode
-Y   Put drive to sleep
```

On Windows you can use [HDParm for Windows](https://sites.google.com/site/disablehddapm/home?pli=1), a Freeware implementation.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing native buildin to Windows for that.
However the well-known Linux utility HDPARM also has a Windows version.
Note that you will have to run it from a CMD or Powershell prompt that was started with "Run as Administrator", but that is normal for these kind of low-level utilities.